# Finding the shortest number of segments needed to connect two graphs whose edges lie on lattice points?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Any algorithms that would help? I'm gunning at something to help me nail this problem:

Hearing that the latest fashion trend was cows with two spots on their hides, Farmer John has purchased an entire herd of two-spot cows. Unfortunately, fashion trends tend to change quickly, and the most popular current fashion is cows with only one spot! FJ wants to make his herd more fashionable by painting each of his cows in such a way that merges their two spots into one. The hide of a cow is represented by an N by M (1 <= N,M <= 50) grid of characters like this:

```
................ 
..XXXX....XXX... 
...XXXX....XX... 
.XXXX......XXX.. 
........XXXXX... 
.........XXX....
```

Here, each 'X' denotes part of a spot. Two 'X's belong to the same spot if they are vertically or horizontally adjacent (diagonally adjacent does not count), so the figure above has exactly two spots. All of the cows in FJ's herd have exactly two spots. FJ wants to use as little paint as possible to merge the two spots into one. In the example above, he can do this by painting only three additional characters with 'X's (the new characters are marked with '*'s below to make them easier to see).

```
................ 
..XXXX....XXX... 
...XXXX*...XX... 
.XXXX..**..XXX.. 
........XXXXX... 
.........XXX....
```

Please help FJ determine the minimum number of new 'X's he must paint in order to merge two spots into one large spot.

Comment: A cow problem in the first day of the first USACO contest?

Comment: @madth3: Are the assignments available online? I tried googling, but to no avail.

Comment: Since it's the current online contest, you have to register to be able to check them. They won't be public until later. Their tradition of using cows and the Farmer John is well known in the community. http:\\www.usaco.org

Comment: yah this was my first online contest so I kinda got railed... I saved the problems in case either of you guys want them, email IDs?

Comment: Well, it's not correct to post the problem while other people can still solve the exam. You should've waited til after Nov 14.

Comment: Asking for help in on-going USACO contests is strictly forbidden according to their rules, and contestants who are caught breaking this rule will be banned for life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be just a simple breadth-first search (or wave algorithm as it's sometimes called).

You start at one of the spots, putting each `X` position in the queue. For each position, you maintain a neighboring position which lies on a path from the spot to the position. In each step, you get a position from the queue, put each neighbor to the queue, change their "neighbor" data, rinse and repeat. On top of that, you make sure you don't touch any place that has its neighbor recorded.

In the end, you reach the second spot, end the neighbor data tell you where is the shortest path connecting the two.

Comment: could you explain further? I don't quite follow